# iOS Pressure touch add to homescreen menu

Tags: html, ios, 3dtouch

*/Assuming usage of an iPad or iPhone/*

If I add a website to the springboard the Pressure Touch pops up a menu that says "Share this page".

Does anybody know if that menu is editable or expandable with items?
I would like to add short links of the menu to the item list.

Couldn't find it anywhere....

Comment: Those actions are called Home Screen Actions. You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/home-screen-actions/).

Comment: Thnx was looking in the wrong way.